# Has any immortal ever broken the 'no fighting on holy ground' rule?

Tags: highlander-franchise

In the first Highlander movie and following TV series, there is an unwritten rule where Immortals are forbidden to duel on sacred ground (what denomination considers it sacred doesn't seem to count)- has any immortal ever defied this rule and attacked another on so-called holy ground?

Answer (score 5):

Shortly after the midway point of *Highlander III: The Sorcerer* (AKA *Highlander: The Final Dimension*), Kane challenged and fought Connor MacLeod in a Buddhist shrine, which MacLeod explicitly referred to as holy ground.

From the [Highlander Wiki](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/Highlander:_The_Final_Dimension):

> Despite this, the Highlander dismisses her, choosing to focus on his more immediate goal of drawing out Kane, who has also arrived in the city (via teleportation). **Connor's goal is realized all too soon, as Kane ambushes him during an aikido practice at a Buddhist temple. Despite MacLeod's warnings about Holy Ground, Kane proceeds to attack, laying on a flurry of sword strikes that shatter the blade of Connor's prized Masamune katana. Before Kane can administer the killing stroke, however, a thunderclap of energy shakes the room. Realizing he cannot violate Holy Ground, Kane leaves the Highlander to contemplate his situation.**

---

Shortly before the midway point of *Highlander: The Source*, the Guardian attacked Reggie in a graveyard -- which Reggie explicitly referred to as holy ground -- and quickly bested him, pressing Reggie's own sword against his throat. It appeared that the Guardian was about to behead Reggie, but he was interrupted, first by Joe Dawson, and then by Duncan MacLeod.

From the [Highlander Wiki](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/Highlander:_The_Source):

> **Meanwhile, the Guardian arrives and attacks Reggie and Joe Dawson on holy ground.** In an effort to save Dawson, Duncan throws his katana at the Guardian, temporarily wounding him. The Guardian removes the sword from his neck and breaks it before killing Joe with the broken blade and escaping.

A bit later in the film, Duncan and Methos were having an argument on holy ground -- specified as such by Cardinal Giovanni -- and Duncan lost his temper, knocking Methos to the ground with a punch and drawing a sword against him. After some more words were exchanged though, Duncan threw the sword to the ground and walked away.

---

In an episode of *Highlander: The Series*, an immortal named Kiem Sun challenged Duncan MacLeod to a friendly sparring match on the grounds of a temple -- which he referred to as holy ground -- implying that it wasn't a violation of the rules, provided they didn't hurt one another. The match was very short, with MacLeod proving his superior after a few sword clashes.

> KIEM SUN: Pick up your sword. Indulge me. This is still holy ground; we can't hurt each other here.
>
> <sub>*Highlander: The Series* - S01E03 - "[The Road Not Taken](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/The_Road_Not_Taken)"</sub>

---

In another episode of *Highlander: The Series*, Joe Dawson mentioned that the Watchers have an unconfirmed record of a fight between two immortals in a temple in Pompeii, in 79 AD.

> JOE: But do you think that punk really would've taken you on holy ground?
>
> DUNCAN: Yes. He was ready to kill me, Dawson... on holy ground. God only knows what would've happened.
>
> JOE: **You know, in all our records, there's only one mention of an immortal killing on holy ground.**
>
> DUNCAN: Yeah?
>
> JOE: **Well, it's never been confirmed. It's, well, it's more of a legend... about two guys going at it in a temple in Italy.**
>
> DUNCAN: Yeah, and...?
>
> JOE: It was in Pompeii. 79 AD.
>
> DUNCAN: The volcano...
>
> JOE: Who knows.
>
> <sub>*Highlander: The Series* - S05E09 - "[Little Tin God](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/Little_Tin_God)"</sub>

Answer (score 3):

In the episode  [Little Tin God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander:_The_Series_(season_5)#ep96) some new immortals, who don't know the rules attack Duncan on Holy ground.

Duncan discusses the matter with Joe.

[Transcript here.](https://www.zzickle.com/tv/episodes/highlander/508-littletingod.html)

> DM - Yes. He was ready to kill me, Dawson, on holy ground. God only knows what would have happened.
>
> Joe - You know, in ALL our records, there's only one mention of an Immortal killing on holy ground.
>
> DM - Yeah?
>
> Joe - Well, it's never been confirmed. It's-- I don't know, it's more of a legend... about two guys going at it in a temple in Italy.
>
> DM - Yeah? And?
>
> Joe - It was in Pompeii. 79 A.D.
>
> DM - The volcano.
>
> Joe - Who knows?